# mongodb restrict access for local users

Tags: mongodb, authentication

i have a mongodb database on a windows server and i already created a user on it with below command and it work fine for remote users, but still someone with access on windows server can run mongod command without auth parameter and then he can access the database, how can i prevent this from happening, i couldn't find any solution on web
thanks

```
db.createUser({
    user: "accountAdmin01",
    pwd: passwordPrompt(),
    roles: [{role: "readAnyDatabase", db: "admin"}, "readWrite"]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user with access to the database's files can copy the files to their own computer and run the database themselves.

Any human being with the ability to log in to the database's user account has full access to the database's files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks D.SM, it solved by creating different account on the vps with no read/write access on db folder by the others